# WM_KILLFOCUS for a modal dialog does not work

Tags: mfc

In my application I have a standard MFC modal dialog. I'd like close that dialog when the user clicks outside the dialog window. For that purpose I put `ON_MESSAGE(WM_KILLFOCUS, OnKillFocus)` in the dialog's message map hy hand (the class wizard does not offer that option):

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CTestTreeCtrlDlg, CDialog)
//{{AFX_MSG_MAP(CTestTreeCtrlDlg)
   ON_NOTIFY(TVN_SELCHANGED, IDC_TREE1, OnSelchangedTree)
//}}AFX_MSG_MAP
   ON_MESSAGE(WM_KILLFOCUS, OnKillFocus)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
...
void CTestTreeCtrlDlg::OnKillFocus() 
{
  ...
}
```

Now if I click outside the dialog, the latter of course looses focus, but the OnKillFocus method won't get called for some reason.

Comment: I think WM_ACTIVATE message should be a better candidate to handle this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you patriiice !

WM_ACTIVATE does the job:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CTestTreeCtrlDlg, CDialog)
//{{AFX_MSG_MAP(CTestTreeCtrlDlg)
  ON_NOTIFY(TVN_SELCHANGED, IDC_TREE1, OnSelchangedTree)
//}}AFX_MSG_MAP
  ON_WM_ACTIVATE()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
...
void CTestTreeCtrlDlg::OnActivate(UINT nState, CWnd* pWndOther, BOOL bMinimized) 
{
  CDialog::OnActivate(nState, pWndOther, bMinimized);

  if (nState == WA_INACTIVE)
    OnOK() ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick search -> http://www.itlisting.org/5-windows/964b01901673b4b0.aspx
I am pretty sure it is a better approach to do this.

Comment: When I call SetCapture() in the OnInitDialog, the mouse doesn't work anymore and the mouse arrow is the spinning doughnut.